# I want to make a select menu help command using discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**I use discord.py for my project and i want make a select menu for my help command, i know a lot about discord.py but on the other hand i've been really stuck on it since 1 day, I'm looking for but I don't find it, can you help me please?**

-- Here my exemple ▶ [Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Nov.png)

Comment: Please include a [mre]. See [context menus](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=contextmenu#discord.app_commands.ContextMenu)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Like this ?

```
    @bot.command()
    async def helpi(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help panel!", description="Your Desc")
        select = Select(
            placeholder="Select something",
            options=[
                SelectOption(label=" - Fun", value="1", description="Get all commands according to \"Fun\""),
                SelectOption(label=" - Utility", value="2", description="Get all commands according to \"Utility\""),
                SelectOption(label="❓ - Info", value="3", description="Get all commands according to \"Info\""),
                SelectOption(label=" - Roleplay", value="4", description="Get all commands according to \"Roleplay\""),
                SelectOption(label=" - Economy", value="5", description="Get all commands according to \"Economy\""),
                SelectOption(label=" - Cancel", value="Cancel", description="Cancel this interaction.")
            ]
        )
        async def callback(interaction):
            if select.values[0] == "1":
                await interaction.response.send_message("Test")
        select.callback = callback
        view = View()
        view.add_item(select)
        await ctx.send("ABC", embed=embed, view=view)
```

You Must remove SelectOption with discord.SelectOption or create a variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).